# Top navigation bar in SharePoint with many sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm just wondering if anyone has any advice or tips for when you start having a lot of `Sites` (or `Webs`) in a `Site Collection` in `SharePoint`.  At the moment we have 10 and it's starting to get a bit busy on the top bar, especially on clients with a lower res screen (goes into 2 rows).

Also shortly we will want to add a section in `SharePoint` for every single company project. I'm thinking of creating a `Site Template` that can be used for each project, but we could have a thousand projects a year from now and I have a no idea how to handle navigation for that many sites!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mega menu to accomodate all pages. Good example to see it live would be argos.co.uk

Comment: Yeah those are very impressive, any suggestions for how to achieve that in SharePoint?  Thanks!

Comment: I used this project as a starting point: <br /> https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2010-and-Mega-Drop-Down-Menu-Navigation.aspx <br/> You can download a source code at the bottom. Then it's all about CSS and how you want to store your menu data. You can use a list, but better way would be to use Metadata Term Store as it's accessible through all web application.

Comment: Thanks for that, will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

I've created a top nav bar with an arrow, and when moving the mouse over the right arrow it will scroll horizontally the nav bar on the left (then a left arrow appears to scroll on the other way). But, to do that, you need both JS and CSS hacks (and I use a HTML5 Doctype for my masterpage to force the last rendering engine for IE - Standard Mode). That could inspire you...

[image: Nav bar with scroll]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use folders in your navigation to better organize the tabs.  You may be able to group your subsites by department, function, or some other organizing structure.

For your projects, you may want to create a structure where you organize your projects by year, quarter, month, or whatever is appropriate.  You can do this by create actual sites for each year, quarter, etc or you can keep the navigation organized manually in the Navigation settings.

```
Projects
  2012
    Q4
      Project A
  2013
    Q1
      Project B
      Project C
    Q2
      Project D
```